# Pandas pivot table using custom conditions on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to make a pivot table based on custom conditions in the dataframe:

The dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Area": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A"],
                       "City" : ["X", "Y", "Z", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "X"],
                       "Condition" : ["Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good"], 
                       "Population" : [100,150,50,200,170,390,80,100]
                       "Pincode" : ["X1", "Y1", "Z1", "P1", "Q1", "R1", "S1", "X2"] })
>>> df
  Area City Condition   Population Pincode
 0    A    X      Good   100       X1
 1    A    Y       Bad   150       Y1
 2    B    Z      Good   50        Z1
 3    A    P      Good   200       P1
 4    C    Q      Good   170       Q1
 5    A    R       Bad   390       R1
 6    D    S      Good   80        S1
 7    A    X      Good   100       X2
```

Now I want to pivot the dataframe `df` in a manner such that I can see the unique count of cities against each area along with the corresponding count of "Good" cities and also the population of the area.

I expect an output like this:

```
Area  city_count  good_city_count   Population
A        4        2                 940
B        1        1                 50
C        1        1                 170
D        1        1                 80
All      7        5                 1240
```

I can give a dictionary to the `aggfunc` parameter but this doesn't give me the city count split between the good cities.

```
>>> city_count = df.pivot_table(index=["Area"],
                                values=["City", "Population"],
                                aggfunc={"City": lambda x: len(x.unique()),
                                         "Population": "sum"},
                                margins=True)

    Area    City    Population
0   A       4       940
1   B       1       50
2   C       1       170
3   D       1       80
4   All     7       1240
```

I can merge two different pivot tables - one with the count of cities and the other with the population but this is not scalable for a large dataset with a big `aggfunc` dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method without using `pivot_table`. Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `groupby`+[`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df['Condition'] = np.where(df['Condition']=='Good', df['City'], np.nan)
df = df.groupby('Area').agg({'City':'nunique', 'Condition':'nunique', 'Population':'sum'})\
                       .rename(columns={'City':'city_count', 'Condition':'good_city_count'})
df.loc['All',:] = df.sum()
df = df.astype(int).reset_index()

print(df)
  Area  city_count  good_city_count  Population
0    A           4                2         940
1    B           1                1          50
2    C           1                1         170
3    D           1                1          80
4  All           7                5        1240
```

Comment: When using this, the good city count will not be unique as it will be summing all the duplicate city appearances for Area as well

Answer (score 2):

Add new parameters `columns` with `fill_value` and also is possible use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) for aggregate function:

```
city_count = df.pivot_table(index = "Area", 
                            values = "City", 
                            columns='Condition', 
                            aggfunc = lambda x : x.nunique(), 
                            margins = True,
                            fill_value=0)
print (city_count)
Condition  Bad  Good  All
Area                     
A            2     2    4
B            0     1    1
C            0     1    1
D            0     1    1
All          2     5    7
```

Last if need convert index to column and change columns names:

```
city_count = city_count.add_suffix('_count').reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
print (city_count)
  Area  Bad_count  Good_count  All_count
0    A          2           2          4
1    B          0           1          1
2    C          0           1          1
3    D          0           1          1
4  All          2           5          7
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'City':'nunique','Population':'sum', 'good_city_count':'nunique'}
d1 = {'City':'city_count','Condition':'good_city_count'}

mask = df["Condition"] == 'Good'
df = (df.assign(good_city_count = lambda x: np.where(mask, x['City'], np.nan))
       .groupby('Area')
       .agg(d)
       .rename(columns=d1))

df = df.append(df.sum().rename('All')).reset_index()

print (df)
  Area  city_count  Population  good_city_count
0    A           4         940                2
1    B           1          50                1
2    C           1         170                1
3    D           1          80                1
4  All           7        1240                5
```

Comment: This wouldn't give me the total_count of cities against the good_count

Comment: @PratiekMalhotra - sorry, you are right. rollback to previous answer.

Comment: @PratiekMalhotra - If your question was answered, please accept the most helpful answer by clicking the grey check to the left of that answer to toggle it green. It helps the community. Thanks.

Comment: @jeszrael, In dataframes where I need to aggregate values from multiple columns. I cannot use the "columns" parameter as it would aggregate all the values based on that.

Comment: @PratiekMalhotra - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because not sure if understand... Thank you

Comment: @jeszrael, Have added a population column to try and explain myself better. Let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: @PratiekMalhotra - answer was edited, need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with dictionary of columns with aggregate functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183431/discussion-between-pratiek-malhotra-and-jezrael).